# Hibernate load in Text fields

Tags: java, swing, hibernate

```
private void display() {
   Session session = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    OrderEntry oe = (OrderEntry) session.load(OrderEntry.class, new Integer(2) );
    firstname_tf.setText(oe.getFirstname());
}
```

Hello,
I would like to retrieve Objects from my database in a GUI. I use session.load, but I'm not sure how to transfer data to the GUI. I tried firstname_tf.setText(oe.getFirstname()); but nothing happens. Can please sombody help me. Please excuse my bad english.

public static void main(String args[]) {

```
    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new UpdateUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}


public class OrderEntry  implements java.io.Serializable {

     private Integer orderid;
     private String reference;
     private String type;
     private String cause;
     private String firstname;
     private String lastname;
     private String profession;
     private Set investigationMaterials = new HashSet(0);

    public OrderEntry() {
    }

    public OrderEntry(String reference, String type, String cause, String firstname, String lastname, String profession, Set investigationMaterials) {
       this.reference = reference;
       this.type = type;
       this.cause = cause;
       this.firstname = firstname;
       this.lastname = lastname;
       this.profession = profession;
       this.investigationMaterials = investigationMaterials;
    }

    public Integer getOrderid() {
        return this.orderid;
    }

    public void setOrderid(Integer orderid) {
        this.orderid = orderid;
    }
    public String getReference() {
        return this.reference;
    }

    public void setReference(String reference) {
        this.reference = reference;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public String getCause() {
        return this.cause;
    }

    public void setCause(String cause) {
        this.cause = cause;
    }
    public String getFirstname() {
        return this.firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    public String getLastname() {
        return this.lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public String getProfession() {
        return this.profession;
    }

    public void setProfession(String profession) {
        this.profession = profession;
    }
    public Set getInvestigationMaterials() {
        return this.investigationMaterials;
    }

    public void setInvestigationMaterials(Set investigationMaterials) {
        this.investigationMaterials = investigationMaterials;
    }
}
```

Mapping File

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="forensikmysql.entity.OrderEntry" table="order_entry" catalog="forensik_db" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="orderid" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="orderid" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="reference" type="string">
            <column name="reference" length="20" />
        </property>
        <property name="type" type="string">
            <column name="type" length="50" />
        </property>
        <property name="cause" type="string">
            <column name="cause" length="50" />
        </property>
        <property name="firstname" type="string">
            <column name="firstname" length="50" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastname" type="string">
            <column name="lastname" length="50" />
        </property>
        <property name="profession" type="string">
            <column name="profession" length="50" />
        </property>
        <set name="investigationMaterials" table="investigation_material" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="orderid" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="forensikmysql.entity.InvestigationMaterial" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Maybe somebody can show me a way to display data in a GUI using tables and textfields.

Comment: Swing (has own thread - EventDispatchThread) doesn't care that Hibernate notify the view (Swing APIs), all events to the already visible Swing GUI must be done on EDT, there are two ways by wraps setText() into invokeLater or by using done() from SwingWorker

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have an example?